# Referencing a column that does not exist

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite3 query that blows up because a column does not exist.  Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    (colA + colB) colC,
    (colA + colB + colC) colD
FROM
    myTable
```

The query is exploding when colC is referenced on the line to compute colD.  I was hoping that since I defined colC before colD, it would work.

What can I do to achieve what I'm wanting?  I need colC to be computed at the time the query is ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this:

> SQLite does not (currently) make any promises about column names on
>   queries that omit the AS clause.

I would suggest trying this:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    (colA + colB) AS colC,
    (colA + colB + colC) AS colD
FROM
    myTable
```

It's possible that the computed value does not get aliased until the resultset is ready to go... or some other such timing issue. Why not simply repeat the calculation like this:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    (colA + colB) colC,
    (colA + colB + colA + colB) colD
FROM
    myTable
```

This way you avoid having to read the aliased, computed column.

Comment: Hmm... well, my query is quite a bit more complicated than my example, but your strategy essentially works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    colC,
    (colA + colB + colC) colD
FROM (
    SELECT
        colA,
        colB,
        (colA + colB) colC
    FROM
        myTable
) x
```